# IIS Express: Runtime library haspdnert.dll is too old (E0001)

Tags: dll, webapi2

I am using WebApi 2, because I am refferencing old dlls that dont work with .NET 6+. One of the dlls is using haspdnert.dll to create sesion to a remote server, but when¨Controller fires the method which authenticates user against the server I get following Error

[image]

Thanks for help